# In JQuery, why can't I check a checkbox after removeAttr("checked") is called?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I want to check a checkbox if a certain input field is populated.

The solution below works initially. After I enter input, the checkbox is correctly checked. After the input is deleted, the checkbox is unchecked. But after entering input again, the checkbox does not get checked.

```
<html>
<head>
    <script src="jquery-1.11.1.min.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function() {
        $(":input").blur(function() {
            var val = $(this).val();
            var myclass = $(this).attr("class");

            if (val != null && val.length > 0) {
                $(":checkbox." + myclass).attr("checked", "checked");
            } else {
                $(":checkbox." + myclass).removeAttr("checked");
            }
        });     
    });

    </script>
</head>
<body>
<form action="#" method="POST">
  Name is selected? <input id="isNameSelected" type="checkbox" name="isName" class="name_input"></input><br/>
  Name: <input class="name_input" id="name" type="text" name="Name"></input>  
</form>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: use prop("checked", true/false) instead of attr

Comment: val, after manipulation, is probably triggering your else statement. I'd do a console log before your if to see what the value of "val" is.

Comment: It seems to work correctly here: http://jsfiddle.net/m4u8ge2h/ -- but I tried it locally and could repro the error, so nevermind,

Comment: It works well for me... Have you checked the console for errors?

Comment: I'm not sure of the exact issue, but you should really be using `.prop('checked', val != null && val.length > 0)` instead of `.attr` to modify the checkbox state.  Attributes define _initial_ state, properties reflect _current_ state.

Comment: @LcSalazar It does not work for jQuery 1.11.0, as specified by the OP: http://jsfiddle.net/m4u8ge2h/2/

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Operating on the attribute via `.attr()` is what's messing you up; I haven't thoroughly investigated but I suspect it has to do with the juggling that jQuery does with attributes like "checked".

You can replace the whole `if` statement with:

```
        $(":checkbox." + myclass).prop("checked", !!val);
```

That'll check or uncheck the checkbox according as whether the text field is non-empty.

Note that because you trigger the handler for any `:input` element, it'll also trigger when you get a "blur" event from the checkbox.

Also, in my opinion it's a fragile coding practice to rely on the "class" attribute having just one string in it. If you need to group these fields, you can do that either with a container element from which you could use `.closest()` and `.find()` to locate companion fields, or else use a `data-` attribute for what you're currently using the "class".

Comment: @showdev yes that makes sense; I only use `.attr()` when I really know I need it (like getting unmolested "href" or "action" attribute values) so I forget the details :)  In this case I think it was the removal of the "checked" attribute that caused the problem.

Comment: That fixed it. Thanks for the additional feedback on the practice of using class attributes to do this.

Comment: @NateReed glad it's working for you. I'm old enough to have made every mistake possible, so I like to share in cases like this :)

Answer (score 1):

This would also work (and take up 2 less lines of code):

```
 $(document).ready(function() {
     $("#name").blur(function() {
         $('#isNameSelected').prop('checked', $(this).val());
     });
 });
```